# displaying phone number during business hours with php

Tags: php, image

I am creating a joomla template for our business web site. And I would like to only display our phone number during business hours. Our phone number is a image I call out with the following code.

`<div>
<img src="templates/images/phone_number.gif" width="428" height="41" alt="" />
</div>`

Is there a way for me to only display that during our business hours, 9am - 5pm Monday threw Saturday eastern time? I found some code on the internet to display it during certain times but not set for eastern time.

I haven't been able to figure this out and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the code that you found? Really, the timezone would be determined by your server settings.

Comment: From a business point of view, this is a horrible idea, but if you still want to do it, [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$openTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' 08:00:00'); // 8:00 am
$closeTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' 17:00:00'); // 5:00 pm
$currTime = strtotime('now'); // Now

if (($openTime <= $currTime) && ($currTime <= $closeTime)) {
    echo "We're open! Show the phone number....";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, we're closed.";
}
```

Matt